# What are the differences in the difficulties?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I'm a little curious to what actually changes in the different difficulties, and if there is any benefits of choosing a harder difficulty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From personal experience, on harder levels:

- Monsters have more health
- Monsters do more damage
- I *think* they walk faster

However, also on harder difficulties:

- You gain more XP
- Monsters drop stronger and more valuable loot
- Monsters drop more mana

Comment: They do indeed move faster.

Comment: are you sure more monsters spawn?  The only time I see more monsters is with more people.

Comment: @yx: You might be right, I only tested easy with one person.  I'll do some more testing tonight.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the wiki](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Dungeon_Defenders), increasing the difficulty increases the rate of XP you earn and the quality of loot that drops.

Comment: Any idea how upping the difficulty makes the game harder?

Comment: I've noticed the enemies' HP increases. I'm not sure what else(if anything is affected)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I've noticed on harder difficulties is that the monsters are more upgraded than lower difficulties.  The monster upgrade symbol is above the monster and looks almost the same as the upgrade symbols for traps.  These monsters have more health and do more damage.

Its also possible that on survival mode, certain monsters (like the super annoying one that heals other monsters), may show up earlier in some rounds though I'm not 100% sure on this part.